# xubuntu logs me out as soon I login, however I can login as guest

Tags: updates, xubuntu, login, logout

This happened after I rebooted after an update and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

I've tried removing Xauthority with no success.

Comment: What is the output of `tail /var/log/auth.log` ? Or is there any types of hints in `dmesg` or any of the other log files? Boot into single user mode, or live disc.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

and

```
sudo rm ~/.ICEauthority
```

did the trick!